# Extension of the definition of Lebesgue integrals according to anti-derivatives

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, lebesgue-integral

I am realising that the Lebesgue integral is not omnipotent. Let's consider the function $f(x)=x^2\sin (1/x)$ defined on $[-1,1]$ with $f(0)=0$. $f'(x)=2x\sin(1/x)-\cos(1/x)$, so $f$ is a.e. differentiable on $[-1,1]$. $f'$ is not Lebesgue integrable, however, because the integral of its abosolute value over $[0,1]$ is unbounded. I feel it is sensible to define $\int _{[-1,1]} f'(x)dx=f(1)-f(-1)=2\sin 1$. More precisely, define the integral in the following way (quoted from [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/52708/why-should-one-still-teach-riemann-integration))

> The Cauchy integral is defined as follows:
>
> Let $f$ be a mapping of an interval $I \subset \mathbf{R}$ into a
>   Banach space $F$. We say that a continuous mapping $g$ of $I$ into $F$
>   is a primitive of $f$ in $I$ if there exists a denumerable set $D
> > \subset I$ such that, for any $\xi \in I - D$, $g$ is differentiable
>   at $\xi$ and $g'(\xi) =f(\xi)$ .
>
> If $g$ is any primitive of a regulated function $f$, the difference
>   $g(\beta) - g(\alpha)$, for any two points of $I$, is independent of
>   the particular primitive $g$ which is considered, owing to (8.7.1); it
>   is written $\int_\alpha^\beta f(x) dx$, and called the integral of $f$
>   between $\alpha$ and $\beta$. (A map $f$ is called regulated provided
>   that there exist one-sided limits at every point of $I$).

We can show that the value $g(\beta) - g(\alpha)$ is independent of the choice of $g$.

However, of course, being Cauchy integrable does NOT mean being Lebesgue integrable.

In the end, I am thinking about this: apparently, the Lebesgue integral could be extended to a larger class of functions. **What are some sensible ways of doing this?** Of course, we can integrate any function in **the vector space** spanned by Lebesgue integrable and Cauchy integrable functions.

Comment: At least in the real line, have you looked at the generalized Riemann integral? It satisfies a sharp Fundamental Theorem of Calculus.

Comment: $f'$ in your example looks pretty Lebesgue integrable to me ($|f'(x)|\leq 2|x|+1$). It should be $f(x)=x^2\sin(1/x^2)$ instead.

Comment: @MaoWao Right. I will edit it.